# How to create active/inactve thumbnails in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am setting up a "Billboard" for the home page of a site. The billboard will have an active image displayed and there will be thumbnails of the right that are used to change the image on the billboard.

Something like this:

[image: Billboard]

Currently I swap the images like this:

```
        <div id="_bbImage">
        <img src="images/bill1.png" class="bbImage" id= "MainBB"/>
        </div><!--_bbImage-->

        <div id="_bbTab1" class="inactiveTab">
        <a href="images/bill2.png" onclick="swap(this); return false;">
            <img src="images/bbtab1.png" class="bbTabImg" id="bbTabImg1"  />
        </a>
        </div><!--bbTab1-->
```

and the JavaScript function looks like this:

```
function swap(image){document.getElementById("MainBB").src = image.href;}
```

But now, I would like to have the thumbnail to have a different class when Its selected or "Active" to achive this effect:
[image]

I need to accomplish the class switch to active, but I also need to make sure that the previously selected tab gets set back to the "inactive" class again.

I tried something like this:

```
function inactiveTab(name){document.getElementById(name).className = "inactiveTab";}
function activeTab(name){document.getElementById(name).className = "activeTab";}
function inactiveTabAll(){
inactiveTab("_bbTab1");
inactiveTab("_bbTab2");
inactiveTab("_bbTab3");
inactiveTab("_bbTab4");
inactiveTab("_bbTab5");
inactiveTab("_bbTab6");
```

}

with:

```
<div id="_bbTab1" class="inactiveTab">
        <a href="images/bill1.png" onclick="swap(this); inactiveTabAll(); activeTab("_bbTab1"); return false;">
            <img src="images/bbtab2.png" class="bbTabImg" id="bbTabImg1"  />
        </a>
</div><!--bbTab1-->
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, when I click on the thumbnail I just get linked to a blank page with "image/bill2.png" image displayed.

Does anyone know a good way to accomplish this, or can anyone point me in the right directions.

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you could have a look at the following jquery method:

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

It has callback functions, where you can make your content visible / invisible.

Instead of your "inactivateTab" - function, you could use the "hide"-method:

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are using an href for the image inside the  tag. 
an  tag is originally a link to a given url
replace
href="xx.png" with
href="javascript:swap(this); inactiveTabAll(); activeTab("_bbTab1");"

I don't understand what's the original role of the href in your code, but you don't seem to be using it anyway

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `img` elements, use `div`s and put the image into the background (use the `background-image` style). This allows you to define which image should be displayed where in pure CSS. You can also swap images by adding/removing classes:

```
.bbTabImg { background-image: url(images/bbtab1-inactive.png); }
.bbTabImg.active { background-image: url(images/bbtab1.png); }
```

As for inactive, use this jQuery:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

This finds all elements with the `active` class and turns it off. Now you can set one of them active again and the CSS above will load the correct image.